# Reference first element in reserved vector

Tags: c++, vector

What is the proper way to return a pointer to underlying buffer of a vector when no elements are yet in it `(size() == 0)`. I call `vector.reserve()` first, so there is memory allocated.

I've tried the following but it gives differing pointer values for what i expected to be identical values. From what I have googled it also seems that calling `.front()` and `.data()` is undefined when the `size()` is zero. I need to get a pointer to the vector to so that i can pass it to a C function.

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> vec(new std::vector<int>(10));

    std::cout << std::hex 
              << (uint64_t)&vec.get()[0] << " "
              << (uint64_t)&vec->front() << " "
              << (uint64_t)vec->data() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 2b324a4cec20 2b324a4cec40 2b324a4cec40

If you run this code on GCC, `.data()` returns 0. The standard then says that `front()` is undefined since `size()` is 0. As you can see the pointer values differ. What is going on?

[ideone example to play with](http://ideone.com/CZZgzV)

Comment: What is the reason you have a *pointer* to a vector? It's usually not needed.

Comment: This is not possible, you are only allowed to refer to elements that exist. The `data()` function may return a null pointer for an empty vector, even if there is storage allocated.

Comment: This is used in a much more complex case where i'm using a vector with a custom allocator, and the vector's initialization needs to be delayed since it's a member variable (and the allocator is not default constructible).

Comment: Why is this not possible? I see lots of use cases where someone would want to allocate space for something and then memcpy the data in

Comment: Well for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it should not be needed? Try to keep things as simple as possible, at all times. Especially when you need to demonstrate something unrelated to others.

Comment: I'm still confused why &vec[0] differs from &vec.front(). Front does not return an itterator, it returns a reference to the first element, as does [0]. So why are they different? Ah songyuangao has mentioned i never dereference the .get(), this fixes that issue

Answer (score 2):

After reading these comments and more googling it seems that it is not possible to retrieve the underlying buffer for a vector (even if reserved) without invoking undefined behavior if the size() == 0

- > & operator[0] cannot be called because it is UB for empty vectors
- > & at(0) cannot be called because it is identical to operator[] (and does range checks)
- > .data() cannot be called because it guarantees only that
  >   [data(), data() + size) is a valid range, not that the range doesn't
  >   start at 0.
- > &front() cannot be called since it is UB for empty vectors

I personally thing this is an error in the language. Data() should return a pointer to vector if reserve has been called